# Are these ahadith about the Prophet liking women, perfume and food authentic?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, authenticity

Are the following narrations from Ibn Sa'd authentic please can you clarify?

> The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him, said: "I like not from worldly life but perfumes and women." (Ibn Sa'd, Kitab al-Tabaqat al-Kabir, Volume 1, p. 469)
>
> Aisha said: "The Prophet of Allah, may peace be upon him, liked three worldly objects—perfume, women and food. He obtained two and did not obtain one. He obtained women and perfumes but did not get food." (Ibn Sa'd, Kitab al-Tabaqat al-Kabir, Volume 1, p. 469)
>
> Salamah ibn Kuhayl said: "The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him, did not obtain anything from worldly objects dearer to him than women and perfumes." (Ibn Sa'd, Kitab al-Tabaqat al-Kabir, Volume 1, p. 469)

Comment: Ibn Sa'ad's narration are only accepted if they have backup of other narrators.

Comment: @Medi1Saif This is the first time that I hear that hadiths from Muhammad ibn Sa'ad are not to be taken when he is the sole narrator. I think there is some confusion and you are referring to some other Ibn Sa'ad. The OP mentioned Ibn Sa'ad as the hadith is in Al-Tabaqat by [Muhammad ibn Sa'ad](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=1917&bk_no=60&flag=1), but I doubt that the chain of narration goes to the 12th level.

Comment: @III-AK-III to me not I've often read that ibn Sa'ad, ibn Ishaaq al-Waqidi etc. narrations are only considered as trustworthy if there's a backup by somebody else, because of maraseel etc. (in case of ibn Ishaaq even because he used to rely on non-Muslim sources too). However ibn Sa'ad might have a better status compared to his teacher al-Waqidi or ibn Ishaaq.

Comment: Related Question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35490

Answer (score 2):

According to [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/21883) and [islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/93090) , the following similar hadith is Sahih (authentic):

> The Messenger of Allah said: 'In this world, women and perfume have been made dear to me, and my comfort has been provided in prayer.'
>
> [Narrated by , Al-nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/36)

Al-Hakim said it is Sahih , and al-Dhahabi agreed with him.

> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: حبب إلي النساء والطيب، وجعلت قرة عيني في الصلاة
>
> هذا حديث **صحيح** على شرط مسلم، ولم يخرجاه
>
> <sup>— [Al-Mustadrak ; كتاب النكاح](https://archive.org/stream/muasahih/masahih2#page/n173)</sup>

Al-Hafiz ibn Hajar said it is Sahih.

> في حديث أنس المرفوع وجعلت قرة عيني في الصلاة أخرجه النسائي وغيره بسند **صحيح**
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari ;  كتاب الرقاق   , باب التواضع](https://archive.org/stream/WAQ131141/11_131152#page/n352)</sup>

These ahadith have also been narrated by Ahmad , Al-Bayhaqi , At-Tabarani, Abu Ya'la ,and Abdur-Razzak