# Is the hadith "two things of your world were made lovely to me, perfume and women" authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Is this hadith authentic?

> Two things of your world were made lovely to me, perfume and women; and the coolness of my eyes is in prayer.

Comment: Related question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34877/are-these-ahadith-about-the-prophet-liking-women-perfume-and-food-authentic

Answer (score 4):

The *Hadeeth* below is graded *Saheeh* (authentic).

***Hadeeth in question***

> حَدَّثَنِي الشَّيْخُ الإِمَامُ أَبُو عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ النَّسَائِيُّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا الْحُسَيْنُ بْنُ عِيسَى الْقُومَسِيُّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا عَفَّانُ بْنُ مُسْلِمٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا سَلاَّمٌ أَبُو الْمُنْذِرِ، عَنْ ثَابِتٍ، عَنْ أَنَسٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ حُبِّبَ إِلَىَّ مِنَ الدُّنْيَا النِّسَاءُ وَالطِّيبُ وَجُعِلَ قُرَّةُ عَيْنِي فِي الصَّلاَةِ ‏"‏
>   It reached me from Abu 'Abdurrahman An-Nasaa'ee, who said
>   It reached me from Al-Husain ibn 'Eesaa, who said
>   It reached me from 'Affaan ibn Muslim, who said
>   It reached me from Salaam (ibn Sulaiman) Abul-Mundhir,
>   From Thaabit (ibn Aslam),
>   From Anas (ibn Maalik), who said,
>   The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
>
> 'In this world, women and perfume have been made dear to me, and my comfort has been provided in prayer.'

**Collected By**

This Hadeeth is found in [Sunan An-Nasaa'ee, 3939](https://www.sunnah.com/nasai/36/1).

**What the scholars of Hadeeth said regarding it**

[It was classed as *Saheeh* by al-Hakim (2/174), al-Dhahabi concurred with him and al-Hafidh ibn Hajar in Fath al-Bari, 15/3 and 11/345.](https://islamqa.info/en/21883)

**Chain of Narration**

The screenshot below shows two chains, the one described above is the bottom chain:

[image: Chain of Narrators]